# cross browser realplayer detection script

Tags: javascript, audio

Is it possible to detect if realplayer is installed across all browsers? I need to have a script that will be useable in browser from IE8 upwards, and will redirect to another page if not detected. Is this even possible?

I checked arounf the internet, and found a VB script, but that might not be compatible with non-IE browsers. I'm really trying to make this as smooth as possible for the end user

Thanks and fingers crossed!

Comment: I'm surprised RealPlayer still exists! If you want to make things smooth for the end user, then use standard video/audio formats and the video/audio element with a Flash fallback for old-IE.

Comment: the "standard" video or audio formats really don't fit the profile of the site. I am using a dynamically created playlist to produce a series of audio clips that play one after another. Why? It produces a menu based audio site that is accessible for blind people. The new html5 audio controls don't come close. I started the site ten years ago and I made the decision to really bring it up to date, http://daily.pressakey.net is the only part of the site fully updated at the moment, but www.pressakey.net is the older version.